# phpexcel reading incorrect decimal values

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have some values in excel sheet as `75.4`, `66.8`and some as integers `24554`. In database I have set the column type as `varchar(11)`. The problem is that some decimal values are displaying correctly and some are displaying as `75.40000000000001` or `73.6` is read as `73.59000000`. I have 2 environments one local m/c and one workspace . In my local m/c it is showing correctly. So, I am not understanding what might be the issue. Following is my code

```
$sheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0);
$highestRow = $sheet->getHighestRow();
$highestColumn = $sheet->getHighestColumn();

$getValues = array();

for ($row = 4; $row <= $highestRow; $row++){
    //  Read a row of data into an array
    $rowData = $sheet->rangeToArray('A' . $row . ':' . $highestColumn . $row); //gives the sheet values
    if(!empty($rowData[0][0])){ //if row is null
        //  Insert row data array into database
        $getValues[] = $this->getValuesModel($rowData, $data);
    }

}
```

I doubt that there might be some php configuration setting because local and server are different but not sure. Kindly, guide me through this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After digging a lot into this, I got the solution. We can do either of 2 the options:

1. The problem was not with phpexcel but with the `format` of the cell defined in the excel sheet. It was given **General** , I changed it to **Number** and now values are exactly like in excel sheet.
2. To override the floating number precision in ini file. PHPExcel modifies the precision and therefore following is the way we should do:

   ```
    $iniPrecision = ini_get('precision');
    $objPHPExcel    = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($inputFilename);
    ini_set('precision', $iniPrecision);
   ```